# Couldn't distinguish NumberPicker views by AndroidViewClient

Tags: android, automation, androidviewclient

In the application I'm trying to automate with AndroidViewClient there are widgets implemented with NumberPicker. Using AndroidViewClient / culebra I can't distinguish the values / texts presented on those NumberPickers.

Comment: Can you include all or part of the `dump` output?

Comment: # class=android.widget.FrameLayout
no_id1 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/1")

# class=android.view.View
android___id_action_bar_overlay_layout = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout")

# class=android.widget.FrameLayout
android___id_action_bar_container = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/action_bar_container")

# class=android.view.View
android___id_action_bar = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/action_bar")

# class=android.widget.LinearLayout
no_id5 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/5")

Comment: # class=android.widget.FrameLayout
no_id6 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/6")

# class=android.widget.ImageView
android___id_home = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/home")

# class=android.widget.LinearLayout
no_id8 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/8")

# class=android.widget.TextView text=u'NumberPickerSamples'
android___id_action_bar_title = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/action_bar_title")

# class=android.widget.FrameLayout
android___id_content = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("android:id/content")

# class=android.widget.LinearLayout
no_id11 = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("id/no_id/11")

Comment: This is all the mump file created by culebra. The application used is simplest example included in https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker zip file

Comment: This is an image of real NumberPicker widget in our application http://www.filedropper.com/im

Comment: And this is a file created by culebra dumping the image above http://www.filedropper.com/my2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how `NumberPicker` is implemented it does not appear in the dump showing its values.
There may be other solutions but the one that comes first to my mind is to create a wrapper and set the content description as the value (this is done by some other Views too).

```
package net.simonvt.numberpicker.samples;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker;
import net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;

/**
 * @author diego
 */
public class NumberPickerHolder extends FrameLayout {

    protected static final String TAG = "NumberPickerHolder";

    private NumberPicker mNumberPicker;

    final OnValueChangeListener mOnValueChangedListener = new OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            final String cd = Integer.toString(newVal);
            Log.d(TAG, "picker=" + picker + " content description set to " + cd);
            setContentDescription(cd);
        }
    };

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public NumberPickerHolder(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public NumberPickerHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public NumberPickerHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(context);
        mNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(mOnValueChangedListener);
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
        if (lp == null) {
            lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
        addView(mNumberPicker, lp);
    }

    public void setMaxValue(int i) {
        mNumberPicker.setMaxValue(i);
    }

    public void setMinValue(int i) {
        mNumberPicker.setMinValue(i);
    }

}
```

Remember to use this new class in your layouts

```
    <!--   <net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker -->
    <net.simonvt.numberpicker.samples.NumberPickerHolder
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then, in your culebra script you can get the value obtaining the content description

```
# class=android.widget.FrameLayout
net_simonvt_numberpicker_samples___id_numberPicker = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("net.simonvt.numberpicker.samples:id/numberPicker")
print net_simonvt_numberpicker_samples___id_numberPicker.getContentDescription()
```

Comment: I'm building the application that need to have the automation test that the guy above is working on and I can't use this NumberPickerHolder since I have 4 different number pickers in my application and all of them share 1 common onValueChanged listener so I need to set each NumberPickerHolder to that listener, how can I do that?

Comment: the first argument of the `onValueChange` is the picker so the same listener could be used for different ones.